# OData Routing with function on EntityType throws HTTP 404 error

Tags: c#, .net, odata, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a .Net Framework Web application running on .Net framework version 4.7.2.
Newly added OData API Route is not resolving to the right controller & action.
Attribute routing is not working as expected despite the Model rules are followed.
I have masked my production code entities with an example below but the CRUX of the problem is the same.
After nearly a month of research and debugging decided to post this question.
Need help in identifying the possible cause.

I have the following EDM model registered in my WebApiConfig.cs

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Category>("categories");
builder.EntitySet<Product>("products");
builder.EntityType<Product>().Collection.Function("testfunc").ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Product>("products");
configuration.MapODataServiceRoute(routename:"DefaultODataRoute", routePrefix:"", model:builder.GetEdmModel());// configuration is of type HttpConfiguration
```

My Controller looks like shown below:

```
public class ProductController : ODataController
{
    // API works as expected
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("categories({category})/products")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProductsAsync([FromODataUri] string category)
    {
        // Returns a collection of type Product
        ... 
    }

    // API throws 404 error
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("categories({category})/products/testfunc")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProductsTestFuncAsync([FromODataUri] string category)
    {
        // Returns a collection of type Product
        ...      
    }
}
```

Wanted to understand if its method naming causing the problem or if anything else to be fixed here ?

localhost:port/categories("TestCategory1")/products -> working
localhost:port/categories("TestCategory1")/products/testfunc -> throws 404 error. Controller Selector resolves to default categories entity / controller. But it should resolve the API method